# execution order of expressions in a list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given the following expressions:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

A matrix is created, then a list comprehension is executed to create a flat list. The comprehension runs from left to right.

```
flat = [x for row in matrix for x in row]
```

Subsequently for each row in the matrix its values are squared. How is this comprehension evaluated?

```
squared = [[x**2 for x in row] for row in matrix]
```

Comment: let me review that post... thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comprehension is equivalent to:

```
flat = []
for row in matrix:
    for x in row:
        flat.append(x)
```

The second comprehension is equivalent to:

```
squared = []
for row in matrix:
    tmp = []
    for x in row:
        tmp.append(x**2)
    squared.append(tmp)
```

(Except for creating additional variables in the enclosing scope like `x`, `row`, `tmp`.)

Comment: thanks for the clear concise sample...

Comment: @wim right, I overlooked those. The `del`-ing is probably unnecessary to get the point across.